# can not extend FragmentActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to extend FragmentActivity but the error is "FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type"
How can I resolve?

```
public class Info_page extends FragmentActivity  {
```

Comment: make sure that android support library is associated with your project. why do people downvote easy questions? **Easy questions need answers too.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add v4 support library, follow steps:

- Right click on your project folder
- Build path-> Configure build path
- Add External Jars
- Select "android-support-v4.jar" file (It'll be located in Android "android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support")
  then press OK.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get this error : cannot be resolved as type you probably didn't import the missing class.
try to add `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`
And try to google before asking for help here... Or to search the site for a similar question.